# how do i turn this $.ajax request into a WebClient execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

- I have a page called:  tar-url.com
- I want to ping target page with a PUT request viai C#.
- I want to return a Success or Error to client.

This exists and works with all clients NOT IE.

```
    var xml = "[XMLDOC]";
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: "multipart-form",
        url: "tar-url.com",
        headers: {Authorization: "Basic herpderp="},
        data: xml
        success: function(){console.log("success");},
        error: function(){console.log("error");}
    });
```

This is the request i normally do.  It works in my old format, but there is 1 hitch, it doesnt work in IE9,  SO i came up with this brilliant idea;  Have my server do it, not the browser.

I create a Generic Handler:  *gHand.ashx* which allows me to carry out my calls.

I do this for some other calls, but it is simple GET requests, that return some JSON.  Here is where i need help.

I create my method as given in C#:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    WebClient wsb = new WebClient();
    //pass *tar-url.com here*.
    string url = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
    //pass contentType here.
    string ct = context.Request.QueryString["contextType"];
    string type = context.Request.QueryString["type"];
    string headers = context.Request.QueryString["headers"];
    //not sure how to access the xml?
    // something like this?
    string xml = context.Request.QueryString["save"];

    //HERE I NEED TO ASSIGN REST OF STUFF TO *wsg*

    string response = wsb.DownloadString(url);
    context.Response.Write(response);

}
```

How i Call it in javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"gHand.ashx",
    type: "get",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        save: xml,
        type: "PUT",
        url: "tar-url.com",
        contentType: "multipart/form",
        headers:{ Authorization: "Basic HerpDerp="}
    }),
    success: function(){...},
    error: function(){...}
});
```

My calls are all seeming to be correct in the sense that i can build a WebClient and execute similar scripts, but it seems that this particular set up boggles my mind.

**Edit:**  Has anyone any idea?

Comment: What's this `multipart-form`? There's no such valid content type. Did you mean `multipart/form-data`? Also you seem to be sending some XML payload. Why is not the content type then set to `text/xml`?

Comment: I think thats what i meant, Multipart/form-data.   It is submitting an XML doc to a server and possibly also up to N files.  I am tempted to just wrap the files in a different call.  Was not sure though.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to change the type of request to PUT atm.  I am not sure if it allows such, i am not sure if i would set it in the headers, OR sort of Credentials.  I did not see any methods for adjusting type at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send your data to the server, you will want to decode it.

example:

You are sending a map of:

```
{
save:xml,
url: url,
type:type,
contenType: ct,
headers:{...}
}
```

So you can look at that and say, similar to how it says:

```
string url = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
```

and proceed as normal.  Your REQUEST TYPE is the last thing you should check because it determines HOW your WebClient object will react.

Since data is going to be saved, instead of you doing

```
wsb.DownloadString(url);
```

which is more or less a get request, you would want to do something like:

```
wsb.uploadString(URL, METHOD, DATA);
```

Since you are pushing an XML DOC, or:

```
wsb.uploadData(URL, METHOD, DATA);
```

if you are uploading images.

Source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

It doesnt matter which order you assign variables, but when you call uploadData, it is executing the webclient request.  There is NOT an wsb.execute() command.